# One-To-One relationship with nullable foreign keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework, one-to-one

I want to create One-To-One relationship in EF where Foreign Keys can be null (So, It can be called 0..1-to-0..1)

```
public class ProductInstance
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int SaleId { get; set; }
    public Sale Sale { get; set; }
}


public class Sale
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ProductInstance ProductInstance { get; set; }
}
```

`FluentAPI` configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Sale>()
   .HasOptional(x => x.ProductInstance)
   .WithOptionalPrincipal(x => x.Sale);
```

But it's generate two columns in table `ProductInstance`:

- `Sale_id` - foreign key
- `SaleId`

Here is generated migration code:

```
 CreateTable(
            "dbo.ProductInstances",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    SaleId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Sale_Id = c.Int(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Sales", t => t.Sale_Id)
            .Index(t => t.Sale_Id);
```

How can I do to get only one column `SaleId` which will be Foreign key?

Comment: Why do you create both an association to a Sale instance and a property which holds the Id of the Sale instance ?  That's the reason why 2 columns in your table are created.

Comment: EF stands for Entity Framework, so it only works with data's as Entities not value-object. maybe in latter version it also supports the value-objects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EF does not support `one-to-one` associations with explicit FK property - there is no `HasForeignKey` fluent API and if you try to workaround it with `ForeignKey` data annotation, you'll get multiplicity exception during the migration.

The only solution is to remove the `ProductInstance.SaleId` property, ending up with model:

```
public class ProductInstance
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Sale Sale { get; set; }
}

public class Sale
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ProductInstance ProductInstance { get; set; }
}
```

and configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Sale>()
   .HasOptional(x => x.ProductInstance)
   .WithOptionalPrincipal(x => x.Sale)
   .Map(a => a.MapKey("SaleId"));
```

Answer (score 7):

### One-to-zero-or-one relationship:

A one-to-zero-or-one relationship happens when a primary key of one table becomes PK & FK in another table in a relational database such as SQL Server.

**One-to-zero-or-one with Data Annotation as follows:**

```
public class ProductInstance
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Sale Sale { get; set; }
}


public class Sale
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("ProductInstance")]
    public int ProductInstanceId { get; set; }

   ///write here other properties

    public virtual ProductInstance ProductInstance { get; set; }
}
```

**One-to-zero-or-one with Fluent API as follows:**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ProductInstance>()
                .HasOptional(s => s.Sale)
                .WithRequired(ad => ad.ProductInstance);
```

In above case, a `ProductInstance` can be saved without `Sale` but the `Sale` entity cannot be saved without the `ProductInstance` entity. ***Keep in min in the above case, A `ProductInstance` cannot have more than one `Sale`.***

### One-to-One relationship:

We can not configure a one-to-One relationship between entities where both ends are required, meaning that the `ProductInstance` entity object must include the `Sale` entity object and the `Sale` entity must include the `ProductInstance` entity object in order to save it. One-to-one relationships are technically not possible in MS SQL Server. But we can configure one-to-One relationship between entities where both ends or at least one end is optional as follows:

**One-to--one with Data Annotation as follows:**

```
public class Department
{
    [Key]
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

    ForeignKey("Person")]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}


public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Department")]
    public int? DepartmentId { get; set; }


    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
}
```

**One-to-one with Fluent API as follows:**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
                .HasOptional(pi => pi.Department)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(s => s.DepartmentId);
```

Comment: @Alexey Markov, Test my code!! If it works as you expected, mark it as answer to help other people with the similar problem!!

Comment: Your code works, but in this case Sale REQUIRED ProductInstance, but I don't know that. The main problem there - nullable foreign keys. Ivan Stoev says that this is not supported. So I removed Foreign Key property from my model and use only Navigation Property

Comment: @Alexey Markov, You are missing the important point!! In case of  One to One or one to-zero relationship you don't need nullable foreign key explicitly !! foreign key is by default nullable..According to your code sale is by default nullable..Run the code and test it!!

Comment: I understand you. My problem was that I want ForeignKey property in my model for easy making relations `instance.SaleId = ...` without loading intance and use navigation property. But i see, it's impossible to get explicit nullable foreign keys in One-to-One. So, now I use only navigation property (bit less comfortably) and now I don't care about Foreign key field name - SaleId, Sale_id - no matter.

Comment: Glad to help you!!