# Deleting association between one or zero to one entities with EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework

I have entities set up something like this:

```
public class MyThing
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual MyOtherThing { get;set; }
}

public class MyOtherThing
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual MyThing MyThing { get; set; }
}
```

My intention is that 'MyThing' can have one or none of MyOtherThing, and I also want a navigation link from MyOtherThing to it's parent.

I have configured the following EntityBaseConfiguration for the 'MyOtherThing' entity:

```
this.HasOptional(x => x.MyThing)
    .WithOptionalPrincipal(x => x.MyOtherThing);
```

I can assign and modify MyOtherThing to MyThing no problem, but when I want to unassign 'MyOtherThing' from 'MyThing', how do I do this?

I tried the following:

```
myThing.MyOtherThing = null;
```

and then editing the entity by setting the *EntityState.Modified* state, but this didn't remove the association between the entities.

I tried adding the following to my MyThing entity, but this resulted in an EF 'Multiplicity is not valid' error when updating my database model:

```
public int? MyOtherThingId{ get; set; }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would you please say which one is Principal Entity and which one is dependent entity?

Comment: I have updated the question with the EntityBaseConfiguration that I used - 'MyOtherThing' is the Principal entity I think - this is the one with the navigation property. It's the MyThing entity where I want to actually store the associated MyOtherThing ID.

Comment: Here read my answer! hope it will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40697264/one-to-one-relationship-with-nullable-foreign-keys/40697333#40697333

Comment: @TanvirArjel, I don't have any issue with the relationship, my question is about how to remove the association between the entities (without deleting the records themselves).

Comment: You should get `MyThing` from the database and `Include()` `MyOtherThing`. Then setting it to null will have effect.

Comment: You may be correct @GertArnold, I'll give that a try tomorrow and return here. Feel free to create an answer so that I can mark it as the answer if it does indeed fix the problem.

Comment: @GertArnold, I thought Include() only works against collections of child entities, no?  In this case, the relationship is one (or zero) to one.

Comment: @CiaranGallagher `Include` works for *both* collection and reference navigation properties. When the entity has no explicit FK, w/o loading the reference navigation property (either by `Include` or lazy, e.g. `_ = myThing.MyOtherThing;`), it's `null` so setting it to `null` has no effect.

Comment: Thanks @GertArnold and Ivan, if you put your comments in an answer I can mark it as the answer. This solved the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried the following:
>
> ```cs
> myThing.MyOtherThing = null;
> ```

If you want to remove an optional *dependent* entity (here: `MyOtherThing`) from a *principal* entity (here `MyThing`) by setting it to `null`, you have to pull the entity from the database with the dependent entity included, for example:

```cs
var mything = context.MyThings.Include(m => m.MyOtherThing)
              .Single(t => t.Id == idValue);
```

(It's also OK when the belonging `MyOtherThing` is loaded into the context later, for example by lazy loading).

Without `Include`, `myThing.MyOtherThing` already is `null` and EF doesn't detect any change. Note that the statement `myThing.MyOtherThing = null;` doesn't execute lazy loading, which is a bit confusing because with collections the behavior is different.

By the way, the dependent entity can also be removed from the database directly, which is more efficient.

```cs
var ot = context.Set<MyOtherThing>().Find(idValue);
context.Set<MyOtherThing>().Remove(ot);
context.SaveChanges();
```