# .NET MVC one to one relationhsip

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database

I am designing a Room Planner and Scheduler for university classes in ASP.NET 5 using c#.
Currently, I have a model for university classes and a model for Timeslots.

It should be possible to create them independent of each other without having a connection at first. It should then be possible to assign each timeslot exactly one class or each class a timeslot.

What would be the best way to implement this connection?
I thought about having some kind of intermediate / junction table but I want to avoid that a class can take place in more than one classroom and vice versa.

```
public class SchoolClass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }

    }
```

```
public class Timeslot
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public bool Occupied { get; set; }

        public Room Room { get; set; }
        public int RoomId { get; set; }

        public Weekday Weekday { get; set; }

        public TimeSpan Start { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan End { get; set; }

    }
```

Any help is much appreciated since I'm kinda stuck on the implementation

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework or something else for your model?  Does this help?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40697264/one-to-one-relationship-with-nullable-foreign-keys

Comment: Yes, I am using ef for this. I have also seen the issue you linked the problem is ef 5 doesn't seem to have the "optional option" in the fluent API

Comment: Maybe someone can answer this in the context of EF5, but that is old and I believe MS recommends always using the latest version of EF if possible.

Comment: yes, I am talking about version 5 of .Net, not ef don't know if there is a difference. Still, I need to get it working on this version whether it's recommended by MS or not.

Comment: .NET and EF each have their own versioning.  It would help to know what version of EF you are on, and whether it's EF or EF Core.